# Firebase analytics ; Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, build.gradle

I'm confused with the error, it says :

> C:/Users/me/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/1f103d8a325f21e988dfb800e5be1a7d/transformed/jetified-firebase-analytics-ktx-20.0.2-api.jar!/META-INF/java.com.google.android.libraries.firebase.firebase_analytics_ktx_granule.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.16.

Here is my build.gradle (project) :

```
    ext{
        kotlin_version = "1.3.72"
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

and the build.gradle (:app) :

```
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.3')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.2.6'
```

Is there anything that I missed in my codes ?

Comment: Any reason you're using such an old kotlin version? It's at 1.6.10 now

Comment: @TylerV it shown `Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)` if I use newest version